# Nginx uri rewriting per domain

Tags: nginx

I have few domains pointing to the same server, for example:

```
server_name www.domain1.dev www.domain2.dev www.domain3.dev
```

Most of the configurations are the same, and they are pointing at the same php file, but i have a different assets folder for each domain:

```
/www.domain1.dev/assets/
/www.domain2.dev/assets/
/www.domain3.dev/assets/
```

that's why i want to rewrite requests like `http://www.domain1.dev/assets/*` into `http://www.domain1.dev/www.domain1.dev/assets/*`

Was trying to play with `location - return`, but didn't find how to get current domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently requested domain name can be in `$host` or `$http_host`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) for the differences.

For example:

```
location ^~ /assets {
    root /path/to/root/$host;
}
```

Or:

```
location ^~ /assets {
    return 301 /$host$request_uri;
}
```

An alternative approach would be to separate your domain names into separate `server` blocks and use an `include` statement to pull in the common content.

Comment: just tested the 2nd example. it works with http://www.domain1.dev/assets/ but doing nothing with links like http://www.domain1.dev/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I will incorporate your comment into my answer.